# Can a A2212/6T ,2200Kv motor with 8” inch propeller can lift an rc plane?

Tags: fixed-wing

I have 4 motors installed in my rc Aircraft, A2212/6T 2200kv BLDC with 8” propeller can it fly a rc air craft weigh 3000gms, if not directly from
ground , if i throw it in the air like gliders will it fly?

Comment: What voltage battery are you using? The amount of power your motors produce will depend on the voltage of your battery. Also, have a look at https://ecalc.ch/motorcalc.php

Comment: im using 3s 11.1v lipo battery

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of googling for that motor and found some data [here](http://www.flybrushless.com/motor/view/50) and [here](https://www.4-max.co.uk/A2212-6T-2200kv.htm). Both suggest a 6" prop as the biggest the motor can handle. A GWS 6x3.5 is quite a thin prop, which is probably why the second link only has it drawing 120W, while the first uses an APC E 6x4 to draw 260W.

The first says up to 837g of thrust, the second 470g. Neither are enough to keep a 3000g plane in the air. You'll need at least 300W of continuous power for basic flight, double that for aerobatics.

Note that an 8" prop will draw almost twice the power of a 6" prop, which is far too much for that motor. 150w is about the maximum it can handle continuously.

2200kv motors are high-speed motors, for fast models like flying wings. You might be better with a 1000Kv motor, which could turn an 8" prop. You'll still need to go to a larger motor though.